# Angular 2/4 can't get json response to show in html component

Tags: json, angular

So I'm trying to return my JSON response into the html component and I have no luck after trying for hours and numerous google/stackoverflow searches. When I use console.log the results show, when I try to show the results in the html component I get nothing. But when I return the results inside an alert i get [object, object]. Can anyone help?

BTW im trying to include the result in *ngif and as text.

data.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, HttpModule, RequestOptions, Headers } from 

'@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


@Injectable()
export class DataService  {

  constructor(public http_: HttpClient) {  }

  userInfo_(a){
    let formData_ = new FormData();
    return this.http_.post('/requests/userInfo.php', formData_)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res[a]);
        var data = res[a];
      }
    );
  }
}
```

account.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';

import { DataService } from '../data/data.service';


import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentType:string;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private http_: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    alert(this.dataService.userInfo_('type'));
  }
  var currentType = this.dataService.userInfo_('type');
}
```

account.component.html

```
<div> {{ currentType }}</div>
<div *ngIf="currentType == 'User'">I'm a user</div>
```

JSON response

```
{"type":"User"}
```

Sorry if the code is a bit messy, i've tried a lot of things out.

Comment: var currentType is outside of any method but still not a property

Comment: It looks completely messy you are right. If I am not mistaken you should do your service method like that:
`userInfo_(a){
    let formData_ = new FormData();
    return this.http_.post('/requests/userInfo.php', formData_)
    .subscribe(res => res[a]);
  }`

or I think better option is:
`userInfo_(a){
    let formData_ = new FormData();
    return this.http_.post('/requests/userInfo.php', formData_);
  }
`
and than:
`ngOnInit() {
  this.currentType = this.dataService.userInfo_('type').subscribe(res=>res)
  }`

Comment: userInfo_ is returning a subscription, not an observable or the data itself.

Comment: @KirkLarkin could you please write example code? im still new to angular

Comment: The existing answers are close enough to a working solution. Another answer is not needed at this stage.

Comment: I know they make sense but i need getting errors. Don't know where else to look or what else to try. I dont know if its a TS error or me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your userInfo is not returning a thing it should be

```
userInfo_(a){ 
 let formData_ = new FormData(); 
 return this.http_.post('/requests/userInfo.php', formData_).subscribe(res => res[a]);
}
```

and your `this.currentType` variable should be inside some method e.g. `ngOnInit`

Personally I do this stuff like this:

```
userInfo_(a){ 
   let formData_ = new FormData(); 
   return this.http_.post('/requests/userInfo.php', formData_); 
}
```

and than
`ngOnInit() { 
     this.dataService.userInfo_('type').subscribe(res=>{
    this.currentType = res['type'];
    })}`

Comment: Im getting... Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'string'. Im so confused, what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Right, sorry, instead `this.currentType = res;` do `this.currentType = res.type;`

Comment: Im getting.. Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: right it could be TS error try to `this.currentType = res['type']` or set type for `currentType:any` (not recommended) or `this.currentType = (res.type as string)` or create Interface for `res`

Comment: YES IT WORKS NOW changed res.type to res['type']

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Comment: is not the same answer posted above?

Answer (score 0):

Your service should return an observable, change it as

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService  {
  constructor(public http_: HttpClient) {  }
   userInfo_(a){
   let formData_ = new FormData();
   return this.http_.post('/requests/userInfo.php', formData_); 
  }
}
```

you should use **`this`** instead of **`var`** and place it inside **`ngOnInit()`**

```
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentType:string;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private http_: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.userInfo_('type').subscribe(res=>
     this.currentType = res.type;
   )}
 }

}
```

Comment: this.currentType = this.dataService.userInfo_('type'); is still outside of any method

Comment: @sajeetharan I tried just now and i get.. 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: @Vega could you please give me an example of what i could do? Thanks

Comment: @Edddddday what does this print console.log(this.dataService.userInfo_('type'));

Comment: @sajeetharan it prints User. No quotes or curly braces

Comment: did yoyu try adding inside ngOnInit()

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes and i get nothing

Comment: One note: `userInfo_` method returns `Subscription`

Comment: @yurzui could you please write example code, im still new to angular

Comment: @Sajeetharan im getting.. Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: this.currentType = res.type;

Comment: Im still getting the same message